# Center align md-tab-group Header Labels

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I want to center my tab bar where the labels are displayed so that i can add a side bar on the left that is connected to the tabs.Here's my code:

```
 <div class="flex-container">

  <div class="flex-item1">
    <md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="PERSONAL">Personal content</md-tab>
      <md-tab label="SOCIAL">Social content</md-tab>

      <md-tab label="BUSINESS">Business content

        <b-app></b-app>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tab-group>
  </div>


<div class="flex-item2">
  <div class="item item-5" fxLayout="column">
    <md-input-container class="search-area">
    <input mdInput placeholder="search" >
    <!--md-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up"></md-icon-->
    </md-input-container>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45270786/1791913

Comment: Thank you but i don't want it to stretch,i want them to move to the center

Comment: Material provided `md-center-tab` property, dont have an idea yet how to do that in Material2, maybe override the css ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Approach 1 using [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) ( Recommended )

::ng-deep works great in this case, however it maybe depreciated going forward. The recommended way is to use ViewEncapsulation.

In your component, add the following encapsulation:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    ....
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Add the following in your component.css:

```
.mat-tab-labels{
    justify-content: center; /* align items in Main Axis */
}
```

Link to [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/jdSQ3RCWJO98QJNTcDmy?p=preview) with `ViewEncapsulation.None`

---

> Approach 2 using ::ng-deep

Add the following in your component.css:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-labels{
    justify-content: center; /* align items in Main Axis */
}
```

Here is a link to [PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/2gELUBiFKmUrSpHTQk6v?p=preview).

Comment: I have always used ng-deep, but I never liked that idea. I am happy I found your answer, because I did not know about the encapsulation decorator.